# Flushing in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I would like to manually flush JPA cache in my tests. After inserting records via spring-data, I do a `.exists()` to check, and that actually takes a few seconds and, if there are constraint issues, they only show up on the `.exists`, not on the insert code itself.

What can I do? Autowired `SessionFactory` exists, but calling its `getCurrentSession().flush()` doesn't do anything.

```
<beans profile="test">
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">   
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

while this:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean">    
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

causes `org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!`

Comment: Why would you use a Hibernate session to flush? Use EntityManager.flush().

Comment: Because I have no access to EntityManagers, I am using spring-data

Comment: So what? Inject the entity manager using `@PersistenceContext EntityManager em;`.

Comment: Ok, put it as an answer and I'll upvote it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was successful by subclassing my `spring-data` `Repository` classes from `JPARepository`, and then using `repo.flush()`

Note of warning -- the flush flushes all cached objects, not just the ones managed by the repository. So if your Repository is `public class BookRepo implements JPARepository<Book>`, calling `bookRepo.flush()` will also flush all your `Author`, `Reader`, and w/e objects too.